# replace column values while searching from another table

Tags: t-sql

I have a below column values in a table

```
Destination
DELLKO
DELBOM
DELVGA 
BOMIXY
```

and so on

and another table with the following data

Table name -- CITY

```
CityName    Code
Agartala    IXA
Agatti      AGX
Agra        AGR 
Akola       AKD
Allahabad   IXD
Aurangabad  IXU
Siliguri    IXB
Bareilly    BEK
Lucknow     LKO
DELHI       DEL
BOM         MUMBAI
```

and so on

now I would like the output something like that

```
DELHI|Lucknow
DELHI|MUMBAI
```

whith the help of Table CITY i.e. wherever destination column has DEL it should be replace by DELHI append pipe sign and search LKO and append LUCKNOW.

Comment: Just join your table using `left(Destination,3)` and `right(Destination,3)` with `CITY` table (2 different joins)?

Comment: Are you sure about the `'BOM'`/`'MUMBAI'` row in table `CITY`? Might it have the column values swapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join CITY twice on the destination codes.

```
SELECT CONCAT(city1.CityName,'|',city2.CityName) AS Destination
FROM Destinations dest
LEFT JOIN CITY city1 ON city1.Code = LEFT(dest.Destination, 3)
LEFT JOIN CITY city2 ON city2.Code = RIGHT(dest.Destination, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if code of city is more than 3 letters or less then 3 letters.
For now, Lets assume that code is 3 letters only.
Try this:

```sql
-- Temp tables for example:
--========================================================

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Abbreviation') is null
    begin
        create table #Abbreviation(
            destination char(6)
        );
    end
else
    begin
        truncate table #Abbreviation;
    end;

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#City') is null
    begin
        create table #City(
            cityName varchar(50)
            , code char(3)
        );
    end
else
    begin
        truncate table #City;
    end;


-- Query:
--========================================================

with cte_main as(
    select
        left(destination, 3) partOneCode
        , right(destination, 3) partTwoCode

    from #Abbreviation
)
, cte_preSet as(
    select
        main.partTwoCode
        , sub.cityName cityNameOne

    from cte_main main
        inner join
        #City sub
        on main.partOneCode = sub.code
)
select
    main.cityNameOne + '|' + sub.cityName

from cte_preSet main
    inner join
    #City sub
    on main.partTwoCode = sub.code;
```